# How do you add a Gridview programmatically to an UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I can't figure out how to programmatically add a `GridView` with buttons to an `UpdatePanel`.

I can do it with simple controls such as buttons and labels, but when I try to add a `GridView` with buttons a full `Postback()` occurs.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">


protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
UpdatePanel up1 = new UpdatePanel();
    up1.ID = "UpdatePanel1";



    Button button1 = new Button();
    button1.ID = "Button1";
    button1.Text = "Submit";
    button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);


    Label label1 = new Label();
    label1.ID = "Label1";
    label1.Text = "A full page postback occurred.";


    GridView gv1 = new GridView();
    //Where the xml gets bonded to the data grind
    XmlDataSource xds = new XmlDataSource();
    xds.Data = xml;
    xds.DataBind();
    xds.EnableCaching = false;

    gv1.DataSource = xds;
    createButton(gv1, up1);
    gv1.RowCommand += new GridViewCommandEventHandler(CustomersGridView_RowCommand);
    gv1.DataBind();




    up1.ChildrenAsTriggers = true;

    up1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(button1);
    up1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(label1);

    up1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(gv1);

    Page.Form.Controls.Add(up1);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}
public void CustomersGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "buttonClicked")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    }
}

void createButton(GridView g)
{
    ButtonField tea = new ButtonField();
    tea.ButtonType = ButtonType.Image;
    tea.ImageUrl = "~/checkdailyinventory.bmp";
    tea.CommandName = "buttonClicked";
    tea.HeaderText = "space";
    g.Columns.Add(tea);
}

protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Label)Page.FindControl("Label1")).Text = "Panel refreshed at " +
        DateTime.Now.ToString();
}

</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>UpdatePanel Constructor Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So how do you add a gridview with buttons programmatically to an `UpdatePanel` without causing a full `PostBack()` if the `GridView` is clicked?

Edit: Other things I have tried

```
   void gv1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    AsyncPostBackTrigger t = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
    t.ControlID = e.Row.Cells[0].ClientID;
    t.EventName = "blah";
    up1.Triggers.Add(t);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried including a placeholder at your page and adding the update panel to this placeholder, rather than to the Page.Controls?

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work. `PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(up1);
        //Page.Form.Controls.Add(up1);`

Comment: Try setting the UpdateMode as UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional. I'm reading some threads at MSDN regarding this same question. One guy had problems with javascript, which is not your case. Another could make it work with this UpdateMode setting.

Comment: Setting updatemode to conditional also didn't work.  I think I have to add each button to the triggers, but I am not 100% sure how to do it correctly.

Comment: AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
trigger.ControlID = "button ID";
up1.Triggers.Add(trigger);

Comment: I don't know the exact controlID so I made a function (Its in the edit in original post). This gives me the following error though:

`System.InvalidOperationException: A control with ID 'ctl01_ctl00' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.`

Comment: This is a little strange, you should be able to retrieve the control ID. If the Cells[0] contains the button, try boxing it to a Button, like ((Button)e.Row.Cells[0]).ID.

Comment: Can't do that because cells return a tablecell instead of a button. So I had to do `e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0].ClientID;` which still didn't work. `t.ControlID = ((ImageButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0]).UniqueID;` This gets me an error about `[InvalidOperationException: Could not find an event named 'blah' on associated control 'ctl02$ctl00' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.]`

Comment: this is strange it should work... well anyway have you considered a KISS approach? (if possible) simply add the update panel at design time with a nested panel and add controls to the panel

Comment: What is KISS approach? And I don't mind having the update panel created at the design time. I just need to be able to add stuff (like tables that contain gridviews that contain buttons into it) programmatically and then be able to do a partial postback.

Comment: Check my response. BTW the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), means _Keep It Simple Stupid_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well according to:

> And I don't mind having the update panel created at the design time. I just need to be able to add stuff (like tables that contain gridviews that contain buttons into it) programmatically and then be able to do a partial postback

Basically I used your code with small changes:

- Removed the binding from the `Init` event and I execute it in the `Load` event
- The `UpdatePanel` is created at design time with a nested panel, and you simply add your dynamic controls to that panel

This code will do it (it works on my environment):

#### ASPX

```
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="myPanel">
            </asp:Panel>
            <br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

#### Code behind

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button1 = new Button();
        button1.ID = "Button1";
        button1.Text = "Submit";
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);

        Label label1 = new Label();
        label1.ID = "Label1";
        label1.Text = "A full page postback occurred.";

        var s1 = Builder<Product>.CreateListOfSize(15).Build();
        GridView gv1 = new GridView();
        gv1.DataSource = s1;
        createButton(gv1);
        gv1.RowCommand += new GridViewCommandEventHandler(CustomersGridView_RowCommand);

        this.myPanel.Controls.Add(button1);
        this.myPanel.Controls.Add(label1);
        this.myPanel.Controls.Add(gv1);
    }

    void createButton(GridView g)
    {
        ButtonField tea = new ButtonField();
        tea.ButtonType = ButtonType.Image;
        tea.ImageUrl = "~/checkdailyinventory.bmp";
        tea.CommandName = "buttonClicked";
        tea.HeaderText = "space";
        g.Columns.Add(tea);
    }

    protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Label)Page.FindControl("Label1")).Text = "Panel refreshed at " +
            DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataBind();
    }

    public void CustomersGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "buttonClicked")
        {
            //int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            this.lblMessage.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Would there be a difference if I wanted to use `<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
            </asp:Table>` instead of panels? I would like to keep the gridviews side by side.

Comment: I think that would work fine, in case you face some problems, you could create the tables dynamically and add them to the `Panel`

Comment: Just a couple of questions to wrap this all up.
Why did you add the binding to the Page_Load?
Why does it take two clicks before it starts to async? (I just noticed this after doing some testing)
Do I have to do it in `Page_Init`? or is that the only place I can programmaitcally add Gridviews?

Comment: It should take only one click to work, (at least in my environment with the code I posted). The recommendation from Microsoft is to create dynamic controls in the `Init` event (when using MasterPage) or `PreInit` (when not using MasterPage). The reason is that controls created after these events, will raise their events much later in the page-life-cycle [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). You can actually call the `DataBind` method in the `Init` event, but a good place to do it is in the `Load` event, (in the `Load` the ViewState has already been binded)

Comment: BTW, You can use: `if (!this.IsPostBack) this.DataBind();` since the grid ViewState will keep its content on each postback

Comment: `if (!this.IsPostBack) this.DataBind();` makes the page keep fully updating itself.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just put the GridView in there at design time and just hide it by setting `Visible=false`?

If you don't know how many gridviews you need to repeat then you could wrap the GridView in a ListView. The concept is introduced here:

- http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html

This might not be the perfect solution I just thought I would offer it seeing as there is a bounty I assume you have hit a brick wall so far.

Comment: The gridviews must be programmatically added because I have no idea until runtime how many I will need

Comment: added an extra idea that would cover this situation